# Is this lattice distributive?

Tags: abstract-algebra, lattice-orders

[image: My lattice]

I have an assignment of determining whether this lattice is distributive and complemented or not. I was able to determine that the lattice is indeed complemented as I found at least one complement of every element of the lattice. I tried to determine whether it's distributive or not but I'm sure if I was correct.

The lattice is distributive if it doesn't contain any sub-lattice that's isomorphic to a pentagon or a diamond. I think that there's a sub-lattice (E, B, A, C, F) that's isomorphic to pentagon, so the lattice then wouldn't be in fact distributive, but I'm not sure about this.

Comment: Try $E(B+C)$ or $E\land(B\lor C)$ depending on what notation you're using for lattice operations.

Comment: E∧(B∨C) = E∧F = E, 
(E∧B)∨(E∧C) = B∨A = B, 
E != B => Distributive law of intersection doesn't apply => There's a pentagon => The lattice isn't distributive. 
Am I correct about this?

Comment: You are right about the pentagon with elements $A,B,C,E,F$; there's another one with the elements $A,B,D,E,H$. You are also right about your conclusion following bob's suggestion.

Comment: Very well, thank you for confirming my conclusion and pointing out the other pentagon, I haven't noticed it at all.